# Cannot add foreign key constraint, - laravel

Tags: laravel

I am having migrations issue. Table is below.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users_articles_likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles');
        $table->primary(['user_id', 'article_id']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

When I try to migrate it. It doesn't push the whole table. Just pushes the `user_id` and `article_id`

and this the error I am displaying in terminal.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL: alter table `users_articles_likes` add constraint
>   `users_articles_likes_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`)
>   references `users` (`id`))

**User** table

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Can you share your `users` table migration?

Comment: I edit the question. update it with the users table. @nakov

Comment: Look at my answer below :) hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is because of wrong data type.. In your users table you have `bigIncrements` which is `Big Integer` data type, and in the other table `integer`

So try this:

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
// or
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
```

make sure you check the `article_id` too.

Comment: oh, thank you for pointing out. it was a good practice for me. Need to wait for the check 10min.

Comment: @parabellum please just don't forget to mark it :) thanks.